# Permission Denied When Accessing Git Repository via npm

Tags: npm

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFwzp.png)

The error message indicates an issue with accessing a Git repository while resolving dependencies via npm. Specifically, it warns about overriding a peer dependency and then encounters an unknown Git error during an attempt to fetch information from a GitHub repository (git@github.com/securedeveloper/js-xlsx.git).

The primary error stems from a permission denial when attempting to read from the remote repository. This suggests that the user lacks the necessary permissions or access rights to fetch data from the repository. The error message advises ensuring correct access rights and repository existence.

```
pm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency npm ERR! code 128 npm ERR! 
An unknown git error occurred npm ERR! 
command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/securedeveloper/js-xlsx.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). 
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
npm ERR! npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
npm ERR! and the repository exists. 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Jenil\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-12T05_18_59_027Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Please post text errors as formatted text 

Comment: pm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/securedeveloper/js-xlsx.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Jenil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-12T05_18_59_027Z-debug-0.log